# What are all the different logs listed in the Dataflow Logs UI?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In the Cloud Dataflow Logging UI I see 4 different logs

1. dataflow-harness
2. dataflow-harness-stdout
3. dataflow-worker-starter
4. shuffle

What does each of these logs represent?

Here's a screenshot showing what I mean.
[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 2):

**dataflow-harness** and **dataflow-harness-stdout** are the logs produced by the java worker harness. The worker harness does most of the work (e.g. applying your ParDo's to data).

Selecting **dataflow-harness** will show all the messages logged by the java worker harness.

We also grab the stdout/stderr of the java worker harness and these logs appear under **dataflow-harness-stdout**. We do this to capture any information which might not be captured by the java logger such as a stack dump if the JVM crashes.

**dataflow-worker-starter** logs messages related to starting up the java worker harness. The startup process basically consists of downloading a job's jars from GCS and then starting the java worker harness. So if there is a problem starting the java worker harness this is a good place too look.

Finally under **shuffle** you will find the logs from the shuffler.